# Inject MavenProject in Sensor constructor as in SonarQube 4.4

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

We currently use SonarQube 4.5.1 and want to switch to 5.2. In preparation for this step we switched the build version of our SonarQube Plugins from 4.4 to 5.2.

The sensor constructors used MavenProject as IoC:

```
public MySensor(Settings settings, MavenProject pom) {
    this.settings = settings;
    this.pom = pom;
}
```

But this no longer works in 5.2.

I found two tickets which seem to relate to this:

- [Remove coupling on Maven libraries](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-3821)
- [Remove injection of MavenProject in module IoC container](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6998)

We need this to read GAV and/or properties/dependencies from the pom.xml.

Is there a way to do this in 5.2?